# Designing a model that retains revision history

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a model for a Django app to handle invoicing, but I'm unsure of the right approach. The invoice must be a snapshot of the values at a given point in time. If you change the price of an item today, it can't affect a prior invoice. I also need to maintain a full revision history for each invoice.

An invoice can have up to forty different attributes, most of which will be left empty. The invoice has different addresses as well, such as the sender, receiver and postal addresses. An invoice also contains lines, which would each have their own values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a transaction table to record changes in invoices.  This table can have links to address tables for different addresses.  You would want to save this Invoice 
Transaction table to the Client Table, so you have the deal points available at any time.

Django has built in fields for saving dates, so you can use those at different places to auto-record the dates in your transaction tables.  Examples of these fields in Django are:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
  created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

My recommendation would be to create a link in the Client table as a `Many-to-Many` to the transaction table.  And each time an invoice occurs / changes.  Join it onto this field.  Then you can reference the transaction table by date, most recent, etc... to get the info that you need.  You can set a `BooleanField`  for the current Invoice, etc.